# How to Sort X-editable json data by values or stop default sorting by key

Tags: x-editable

this is my editable code,
    `jQuery('.billitemname').editable({
            url: base_url+'timetracker/saveEdit',
            source: base_url+'/timetracker/getBillCats',
            type: 'select',
            mode: 'inline'
       });`

and this is the Json data while i am getting in source,

```
{"96":"B2B Calling","68":"Billboards","12":"Comprehensive Planning","13":"Consulting Fees","109":"Content Writing","105":"Convenience Fee","15":"Creative Writing","104":"Digital Video X","55":"Direct Mail","62":"Direct Mail List","17":"Domain","98":"Drone Work","79":"Email Marketing","100":"Google Adwords","20":"Graphic Design","88":"Healthy Website Plan","89":"Healthy Website Plan Set up","21":"Logo Design","95":"Marketing Package","113":"Miscellaneous Marketing","103":"Mobile 360","83":"Online Ad","110":"Online Partnership Package - Brand Level","115":"Online Partnership Package - Strategy Level","97":"Onsite Tech","81":"Pay Per Click","94":"Photo Edits","25":"Photography","74":"Postage","26":"Print Ad","27":"Print Work","101":"Production","93":"Production Supplies","67":"Promotional Items","30":"Radio Ads","28":"Radio Production","114":"Research","102":"Retargeting","90":"Robo Calls","87":"Services","34":"Shipping","35":"Signage","80":"Social Media Marketing","75":"SSL Certificate","91":"Stock Photography","107":"Talent Fees","73":"Trade","37":"TV Ads","38":"TV production Cost","56":"Video Work","92":"Video\/Social Package","51":"Voice Talent","40":"Web Hosting","33":"Web Optimization","84":"Web Work","46":"Website Design"}
```

But it is sorting by default key, So my output is like 

    `<option value=12>Comprehensive</option>.....` so on,